# Using flowfile size as an argument in RouteOnAttribute nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want  to  know if is it possible to  use  flowfile size  as an  argument in  routeOnAttribute  i want to make  expression like that :

```
${filename.fileSize>500}
```

but  it  tells me  that  expression  ought to  return true and my expression returns  string  what should   i do to be able to make new  connection in routeOnAttribute(p.s filename is my flowfile name)

**EDIT 05/17/2019** Correct answer is Andy's. That is the best guidance from us (Apache NiFi team) on the subject. The answer marked "correct" only applies in a few cases where `Content-Length` is set by an upstream processor. Andy's solution, `fileSize` is universally applicable.

Comment: Why you are comparing file Size?.FileSize is not an attribute in which you use.

Comment: I want to check if the flowfile size is less than 500( it means  response is  empty) and  i can  make connection  with emty reponse and then log it. should  i use conetn size  instead of  size  ?

Comment: I meand content length

Comment: Yes you can use ${Content-Length}

Comment: ok  thank you  I have made it like this ${Content-Length:toNumber():divide(500):equals(1)}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Two ways to check empty response present in flowfile.

1.Using Content-Length attribute-->`${Content-Length}`

2.Using Extract Text processor to extracts entire content in attribute.

```
flow_content--(.*)
```

then check `${flow_content:isEmpty():not()}`

It may be helpful for your case.

Comment: It is far preferable to use `${Content-Length}` because extracting the content to an attribute when the content is large will have a very detrimental effect on the performance of the application. Attributes are held in memory and written to the flowfile repository, which is designed for fast read/write and lightweight data. It is highly discouraged to extract the entire flowfile contents to an attribute just to check the size.

Answer (score 21):

Your expression is logically correct but does not use valid Apache NiFi syntax. It should use the `gt` function as below:

```
${fileSize:gt(500)}
```

This will return a `boolean` result.

Answer (score 0):

On the RouteOnAttribute, you can configure an attribute whose value evaluates to true when flowfile content is of certain size.

[image]